# How to Detect Color Combination using python?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I can detect blue color using a Hough Circle, but, i need to detect 5 color that exist and show what is number of robot. How could i detect this combination using python or opencv? any suggestion?

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: one mask per color to be detected?

Comment: that i want to ask you sir.. What should i do? Masked it one by one or any option? @Miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use Hough circles, if your image size is constant per ID. Here's an alternative:

In your ID image, figure out the approx locations of the yellowed points shown below:[image]

You'll have 5 interest points- (x[0],y[0]) to (x[4],y[4])

Let's suppose that one yellow interest point is located at (10,10).

Since you're using python, you can get the intensity of the interest points using:

```
 img=imread("ID.jpg")#read image
    b=[]#declare empty lists
    g=[]
    r=[]
    x=[]
    y=[]

    #save points of interest___
    x[0]=10
    y[0]=10 #likewise for the remaining 4 points

    for i in range(5)
        b[i]=img(x[i],y[i],0)#img is a single ID image
        g[i]=img(x[i],y[i],1)
        r[i]=img(x[i],y[i],2)
    if(b[0]==100 and g[0]==0 and r[0]==255)#Pinkish colour
        print "1st dot is pink"
```

Now you have a total of 15 integers (5 points X 3 colours). You can decide the unique ID based on their values.

Comment: can you give some source code example? i am very newbie here.. get your concept, but cannt implement it.. @Saransh Kejriwal

Comment: I've edited my answer; I've added some more syntax in it

Comment: thank for your answer.. but, can i implement it in a Video format as a image processing.. Or i just can do it in image format? @Saransh Kejriwal

Comment: You can very well do it in video format, since a video is a sequence of images anyway

Comment: what happen if i make a rotation in the picture? can syntax keep detect it?
In video format, we need to detect all combination in all position.. @Saransh Kejriwal

Comment: If the image is rotated, then our interest point may fall out of the circles you've drawn. To tackle that, you need to look into Perspective Transform, which can help you get the upright image of your ID from the video, to run the process on

Comment: Do you know something about Perspective Transform in python that i can learn? @Saransh Kejriwal